# альтернатива метода find js?

Tags: javascript

что можно использовать в качестве альтернативы метода find  js?

Comment: а чем не нравится метод `find`? и какой именно метод `find` имеется ввиду?

Comment: можно использовать filter, когда не было find люди так делали

Comment: @Darth, ой вэй, бежать по всей коллекции даже если искомый элемент в начале? :)

Comment: @Grundy конечно быстрее всего будет искать обычным for, причем с конца

Comment: @Darth, ерунда, был где-то jsperf в котором результаты обхода не зависели от направления. Ну и естественно все от браузера зависит.

Comment: find не поддерживается в IE11